# Need to automate the nightly synchronization of files on the hard drive of a server with a repo in Azure Devops

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, azure-devops, dynamics-crm

Specifically what I am trying to do is create an automated nightly synchronization of the report files (rdl) from an on premise Microsoft Dynamics CRM to an Azure Devops repo.

On Github I found a tool called CRMReportSync that will provide 2 way synchronization of the rdl files from the CRM to and from a folder on the servers hard drive. I'm confident I can customize it so this can be automated through Windows Task Scheduler.

The part I'm not sure is how do I go about automating the synchronization of the files on the server's hard drive with an Azure Devops repo.

I just started learning Azure Devops last weekend and need to have the system in place by Fri 1/31/2020. So any help, even if just pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: launch the tool on a schedule?

Comment: I said I know how to launch the tool on a schedule. The part I'm not sure of and which the tool does not do, is to to synchronize files on the hard drive of a server with a repo in Azure Devops

Comment: why though? why would you want to push random files to a git repo?